# Database json column returning escaped string in laravel blade

Tags: mysql, json, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have saved some Json data in a MySQL column. While fetching the data to a Laravel Blade application the json fields are all escaped. Hence, I am facing issues while reading the json data.

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "json_backup": "{\"id\":\"2\",\"organization_id\":\"1\",\"amount\":\"7800.00\",\"date\":\"2015-05-11\",\"created_at\":\"2015-05-11 07:20:45\",\"updated_at\":\"2015-05-11 07:20:45\"}",
    "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "created_at": "2015-05-12 12:21:16",
    "updated_at": "2015-05-12 12:21:16"
  }
]
```

The json_backup field in the above example is escaped. How do I ensure that this field is not escaped.

Code to fetch the data

```
$activity = Activity::find(1);
```

In the View:

```
@foreach ($activities AS $activity)

       @foreach($activity->json_backup AS $order)

       @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry. It does not work.

Answer (score 1):

@saaz When you are storing the JSON in MySQL, use

`json_encode($json_backup, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)`

HTH

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming on the second `foreach` section.
Please try it in somewhat this way.

```
$json = json_decode($activity->json_backup, true);
```

This would work but can't say it definitely. And even if you have problem refactor the code and create a class with following code:

```
function escapeJsonString($value) { 
    $escapers = array("\\", "/", "\"", "\n", "\r", "\t", "\x08", "\x0c");
    $replacements = array("\\\\", "\\/", "\\\"", "\\n", "\\r", "\\t", "\\f", "\\b");
    $result = str_replace($escapers, $replacements, $value);
    return $result;
}
```

And simply say

```
$json = escapeJsonString($activity->json_backup);
```

This one would definitely work. Hope so this helps.